# 1400 Kv BLDC motor problem

Tags: arduino, batteries, brushless-dc-motor

I have a A2212/10T 1400 Kv (1400 RPM / volt) brushless DC motor and a SimonK 30 A electronic speed control (ESC.) I have connected it to an Arduino. It is not powering up when I use only battery supply, but it does when I connect the Arduino to my computer. I am using a 9 V battery which I have made on my own by connecting six 1.5V cells together in series. Is that because of low voltage or something like that? The ESC datasheet says it can work on a battery anywhere between 7.4 (2S LiPo) to 14.8 (4S LiPo), although it doesn't specifically say that a LiPo battery is to be used.

Also, when I run my motor at 50% throttle, it works at that speed only for a few seconds and then it slowly throttles down to 0%. It also doesn't run at 100% throttle. Why is this happening?

Can anyone help me out with these problems?

Comment: "1400KV motor". That means 1400000 Volt. That's not what you mean. Capitalization matters. You mean 1400 Kv (lower case 'v'): that means 14000 RPM for 1 V applied to the terminals

Comment: @DavideAndrea Speaking of, volt isn’t along with other SI-units unless you are referring to the last name as in Georg Ohm measuring 4.7 ohm on his lab-bench.

Comment: `Kv` actually means "Kelvin-speed", whatever that is. This would be why we have to study basic natural science before even applying to an engineering degree program.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Yeah, I'm sorry, I meant 1400Kv but it's actually 1400 RPM per 1V applied right? I guess what you are referring to is the RPM at 10V.

Comment: There are zillions of ESC units. Which one do you have? What battery do you have? What does the ESC instructions recommend for a battery?  Note there’s a number of critical details you’ve not told us. This is a complex system and details matter.

Comment: @Kartman, I have made the necessary changes and added the information you are asking for. Please check and let me know if you have an answer now.

Comment: You talk about connect 6 1.5V cells in series. What are these cells?  Tell us precisely. My guess is you need to use a LiPo battery. Your 1.5V cells aren’t up to the task. What gave you the idea that they might work??

Comment: @Kartman, Ok so I have used six 1.5V Carbon Zinc AA cells. You can search them with this link: "https://www.amazon.in/Eveready-1015-Carbon-Zinc-Battery/dp/B07Q7561HD/ref=sr_1_10?crid=1JKHU2CLNX6YW&keywords=1.5v%2Baa%2Bbattery&qid=1684247241&sprefix=1.5v%2Baa%2Caps%2C497&sr=8-10&th=1". 
Why I thought they would work is because the added up voltage is 9V and it falls in the range specified. Also, its mAH rating is 1800-2500mAH or more, close to the LiPo batteries.

Comment: AA cells can deliver nowhere near the current a LiPo can produce. Get yourself a LiPo.

Comment: @Kartman, I tried to use these AA batteries as they are WAY cheaper than LiPo Batteries. I just was trying to find alternatives to LiPo's. So, would Li-ion Batteries work?

Comment: "I guess what you are referring to is the RPM at 10V". No, I wasn't.

Comment: @DavideAndrea, But doesn't 1400Kv motor produce 1400RPM at 1V? That's what I read on the internet.

Comment: @winny. Thank you for the correction. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: The 30A speed controller is a clue : you  want the battery system to support 30A to get the best out of it (if the motor supports the same current). AA cells are useless at this level. Pick your Li-Ion carefully, reading their datasheets for max discharge current. Meanwhile, grab a car battery and test with that.

Comment: "But doesn't 1400Kv motor produce 1400RPM at 1V?" Yes. I never mentioned 10 V. You did.

Comment: The cost of AA batteries is immaterial if they don’t work. 18650 lithium ion batteries might work at a pinch. LiPos are designed for the high discharge rates that you get with bldc motors, so they should be your first choice. Other choices might be a car battery as previously suggested, lead acid motor bike battery, 12V SLA batteriy or some LiIon batteries say, from laptops, battery powered drills etc.